# How to avoid binding table knockout in computed array

Tags: knockout.js

I have a Table where I load the values of arrayA which one is ko.computed Array, which one depends of the value of other arrayB.

When I remove an element of array B, automatically the arrayA is updated with the new values of arrayB.

The problem is when for example:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: arrayA()"> 
        <tr><td data-bind="text: $data.value"></td></tr>
</tbody>

javascript:

arrayB.remove(data);
```

When I do this operation in the html the table is reloaded with the previous values of arrayA without the element deleted + the new value of ArrayA.

How can I avoid the reload of the table with previous values of arrayA + new value of arrayA computed? I want only reload the new values of computed arrayA without the previous content.

Comment: can you make us a working fiddle .

Comment: Could you please include all relevant code? My first guess is that there is something fishy going on in your `ko.computed`.

Comment: I am sorry but my code is very long. I have 1 ajax call which one recover a observableArray built with the help of a mapping with mapping.fromJS where the arraycomputed is built.

Comment: I'm afraid without it, we cannot help you. Please provide a minimal extract of your code as an example, either as a JSFiddle or as an embedded snippet. Apart from that - `foreach: arrayA()` should be `foreach: arrayA`. You want to give your `foreach` access to your `computed` itself, not to the _result_ of the `computed`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a `ko.computed`, it becomes a dependant observable, therefore any changes made to an observable that the computed is watching will cause it to update.  This was the way it was designed to work, it's called the Dependency Chain.

I would suggest looking into an alternative solution which doesn't use computed observables to achieve what you are looking for.

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html